# phpexcel - how to get all values from resultset in a loop fromarray

Tags: mysql, phpexcel, phpactiverecord

I can't figure out how to get all datas (rows and columns) from a mysql resultset.
With this code i get not all rows from the my query :

```
$row=1; 
$column = 'A';

$sql = "SELECT distinct c.code, p.gestion";
for ($i = 1; $i <= count($steps); $i++) {
    $sql .= "
        ,(SELECT IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(c".$i.".`delta`),1),'')
            FROM charge c".$i.", totalgestion p".$i."
            WHERE c".$i.".code = p.code
            AND c".$i.".steps = ".$i."
            AND c".$i.".actif = 1) as delta".$i.",'' as comments".$i.",
         (SELECT IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(c".$i.".`values`),1),'')
            FROM charges c".$i.", totalgestion p".$i."
            WHERE c".$i.".code = p".$i.".code
            AND c".$i.".year = ".$year."
            AND c".$i.".steps = ".$i." "
            AND c".$i.".actif = 1) as total".$i." ";
    ;
}
$sql .= "
FROM charges c, totalgestion p
WHERE c.code = p.code
AND c.annee = ".$year."
AND c.type = 1
";

$totalvalues = RefTable::find_by_sql($sql);

    foreach ($totalvalues as $totalvalue) {
        $Code = $totalvalue->code;
        $Gestion = $totalvalue->gestion;

        for ($i = 1; $i <= count($etapes); $i++){
            $Del = 'delta'.$i;
            $Com = 'comments'.$i;
            $Tot = 'total'.$i;
            $Delta = $totalvalue->$Del;
            $Comments = $totalvalue->$Com;
            $Total = $totalvalue->$Tot;
    }   
    $datas=array($Code,$Gestion,$Delta,$Comment,$Montant);

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($datas, null, $column . $row);
         $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column . $row)->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID);
         $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column . $row)->getFill()->getStartColor()->setRGB('3F6E89');
         $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column . $row)->getFont()->getColor()->setRGB('FFFFFF');
         $row++;
    }
```

I get only 5 columns, but there must be 8 because i have made a for loop of the last 3 columns... :
see picture:

[image]

..and normaly i must get

like see picture:

[image]

In my example it can be 5 columns but also 8 or 11 columns, because there are associations. 
I think my for loop is anywhere not correct
So how can i get all values from looping resultset?

Anybody an idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can link more `setCellValue`

```
$column_init = 67; // equals C in ascii
$columns = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($steps) * 3; $i++) {
    $columns[] = $column_init + $i;
}

$values = [];

foreach ($totalvalues as $totalvalue) {
    $totalvalue = (array)$totalvalue;

    for ($j = 0; $j < count($steps); $j++) {
        $values[] = $totalvalue['delta' . $j];
        $values[] = $totalvalue['comments' . $j];
        $values[] = $totalvalue['total' . $j];
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($columns); $i++) {
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue($columns[chr($i)] . $row, $values[$i]);
    }

    $row++;
}
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. Your exemple works good for the known column, but how can i get the other columns who are in the 'for loop'? I get after the first two columns ('code' and 'gestion') min 3 columns, but they can also be 6. The columns are 'delta', 'comments' and 'total'. How to loop inside the foreach for these min 3 columns? I hope it is comprehensible, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Using `fromArray()` instead of `setCellValue()` would be even easier, removing that `for()` loop

Comment: I have changed the second picture. The first two columns (A and B) are outside the loop, after i get the three columns in a loop, so in the picture we see the three columns 2 times (C,D,E and F,G,H).

Comment: Hi Mark, i tried fromArray(), but i get : 'Fatal Error: Cannot use object of type RefTable as array'. I think that i don't know how to put the values in an array.

Comment: @achillix I've edited my answer again. It's a awkward way, but I think it will work.

Comment: @worldask i tried and i get this error message: 'Fatal error: Cannot use object of type RefTable as array in export.php on line 317' on this line are the following code : '$values[] = $totalvalue['delta' . $j];'.

Comment: try `$array =  (array) $totalvalue;`

Comment: @MarkBaker - i have changed my code in the example. Do you see the problem? THX